# pymongo no output for query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

EDIT:
I have somewhat distilled the question.

```
mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({"medicalObjectId": "269"})
print "\n\n"
for this_document in mongo_documents:
    print this_document

print "-------------------------"

pqr = 269
mongo_documents2 = mongo_collection.find({"medicalObjectId": pqr})
print "\n\n"
for this_document2 in mongo_documents2:
    print this_document2
```

My problem is that the first code chunk where I use the number as the key in the query, works. But the second chunk where I use the variable, i get no output.

---

I am a beginner at python and pymongo, so please bear with me.

I have a list as;
row = [1, 2, ...., 100]

I want to query a mongodb collection for each entry in my list.
The collection has the format:
collection = {'pk', 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3'}

I want to call the mongodb connection and iterate through each entry in my list with row[i]=pk and return the other attributes as the output.

ie. mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({'pk' : row[0]})
mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({'pk' : row[1]})
and so on.

The code that I have is:

```
for row in result_set:
    print row[0]
    mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({'medicalObjectId' : row[0]})
    print mongo_documents
    for this_document in mongo_documents:
        print "----------------------------------"
        print this_document
```

however i get no output. where am I going wrong?
if i print mongo_documents, i get

```
    <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0xe43150>
```

Comment: Why don't you use ipython and try to inspect this_document variable. Of course its easier to just look up the API and get the document right within your code, but I will encourage you to play around with it as you are a beginner.

Comment: Despite the comment above, let me explain. mongo_document is a cursor which you will use to get results. you can treat it like an iterator and keep calling its next() method to get the next matched documents till you get StopIteration exception. Or else, the way you have done it in a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the $in operator of mongodb to fetch all the rows at once and iterate through them.

```
mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({ 'medicalObjectId' : { '$in' : result_set } } );
for doc in mongo_documents:
    print mongo_documents
```

I have not tested it, comment below if it doesnt work.

EDIT

```
mongo_documents2 = mongo_collection.find({"medicalObjectId": str(pqr)}) 
print "\n\n" 
for this_document2 in mongo_documents2: 
    print this_document2
```

Comment: It didnt work. 
again there was no output, exception or otherwise. all I got was the my list which got printed.
The entries in the list are ints so datatypes compatibility also isn't an issue.

Comment: Could you edit your question with your current code and also the output you are getting.

Comment: I thibk the main problem is here;

        `mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({'medicalObjectId':row[0]})`

if I use the number istead of the variable, it works.
ie. 

       `mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({'medicalObjectId':'269'})`

works. However, if i use a vriable which has the value 269 will not work.
ie.

`abc = 269
mongo_documents = mongo_collection.find({'medicalObjectId':abc})`
will give no output.

Comment: Why are you using a string in one case and integer in other. i.e. '269' and abc=269?

Comment: hmmm...
does this means that i will have to pass my variables as strings? let me try.

Comment: GAAAAAAHHHH!!!
I can't believe this. it works if I send a string. but an int vaue gives no output. Thanks spic. Can you please put in your answer so I can select it. For reference,

`pqr = 269
 mongo_documents2 = mongo_collection.find({"medicalObjectId": str(pqr)})
 print "\n\n"
 for this_document2 in mongo_documents2:
  print this_document2`

works

Comment: I would still ask you to consider selecting all documents in one go. i.e. running find just once. You can modify the result set to contain strings instead of integers.

Comment: Can you further assist on how to print the object after setting limit = 1. It shows pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fb542b45b50.